# [Spray Client]: Facebook graph API returning wrong contentype

Tags: scala, facebook-graph-api, spray, spray-json, spray-client

Staring with the [Spray](http://spray.io/) Library I tried to make a request to the Facebook Graph API:

```
val responseF: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Get("http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/facebook/picture?redirect=false"))


def receive = {
    case _ =>
      val originalSender = sender()
      responseF onComplete{
        case Success(response) =>
            log.info(response.toString)
            originalSender ! response.toString
          log.info(  """|Response for GET request
                       |status : {}
                       |headers: {}
                       |body   : {}""".stripMargin,
            response.status.value, response.headers.mkString("\n  ", "\n  ", ""), response.entity.asString)
        case Failure(error) =>
          log.error(error, "Could not get Facebook stuff")
          originalSender ! "not working"
      }

  }
```

The main problem is that the contentype of the response is 
`Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8` 
instead of the expected `application/json`

What exactly is wrong with my request?

As `Spray` relies heavily on the content-type for parsing etc.

Comment: Maybe you need to include an `Accept` header if you want to receive a specific kind of response. This should probably be documented in the facebook API.

Comment: I tried with `val getter = HttpRequest(method = GET, uri=path, entity = HttpEntity(`application/json`, "{ value: 42 }"))` but it produced the same result. Any idea how I would need to define it?
`

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution was to just add an acceptance header, but I couldn't figure out how:

```
pipeline( 
    Get("http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/facebook/picture?redirect=false").withHeaders(Accept(MediaTypes.`application/json`)) 
  )
```

Thank to a quick answer on the [goolge group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spray-user) I finally get now the correct content type.